# Current Exaile song in Empathy status

Tags: empathy, instant-messaging, exaile

I switched to Exaile a while back, and the only thing I find lacking is the Empathy integration, if I may call it that. I wish to be able to set my IM status as the currently playing music track. Rhythmbox did that out of the box. Exaile doesn't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/exaile/+bug/427082) on Exaile Launchpad, actually a plugin doesn't exist and the bug is marked as wishlist. On exaile-users group on Google Groups you can find an [interesting answer](http://groups.google.com/group/exaile-users/browse_thread/thread/7d8fc7c7b11d7c78/3ed302a1a1dfc5b6?show_docid=3ed302a1a1dfc5b6&fwc=1) by Adam Olsen (Exaile Developper), the same guy who marked as wishlist the bug.
By the way [here](http://www.exaile.org/files/plugins/0.2.11/imstatus.py) there's the old working plugin.

Comment: can i create a py file, in some directory, so exaile can "include" the plugin? or is it incompatible?

Comment: Adam Olsen says in Google Group answer that it's not compatible with Exaile 0.3.x.x and giving a look at the plugin code I'm not sure that Empathy is supported. But if you're good enough with Python you can try to modify it.

Comment: nah, id rather wait :P